# Why am I seeing a "member is not recognized or is not accessible" error on my WPF User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a custom user control with a public property that I'd like to be able to set in XAML. Here it is below.

**TestControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Scale.Controls.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
```

**TestControl.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public string TestMe { get; set; }
        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my MainWindow.xaml file, I try to include this:

```
<controls:TestControl TestMe="asdf" />
```

However, even though Visual Studio autocompletes the TestMe property, I then see things with a squiggly underline that says "The member "Test Me" is not recognized or is not accessible," as seen below.

[image: The member "Test Me" is not recognized or is not accessible]

I could have sworn I've done something like this before in other projects. How can I access (i.e. set) the public properties via XAML like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to declare your property as `Dependency Properties`

```
namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        //Register Dependency Property

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestMeDependency = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl));

        public string MyCar
        {
            get
            {

                return (string)GetValue(TestMeDependency);

            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TestMeDependency, value);
            }
        }

        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An example of how to do this would be great

Comment: I beleive your project should build as-is. You only need a dependency property if the property is going to be the target of a binding.  I tested a similar scenario just now and it builds as shown in your question.  Not very useful... but builds.  After building VS stops complaining on my machine.

Comment: Thanks so much @MoezRebai! This worked perfectly. One thing to note is that after I included this code I had to build the project again before the error went away.

Comment: Error still persists, although it compiles just fine, the property does nothing.

Comment: Surely he only needs a dependency property if he is binding to it? A normal property should work fine.

Answer (score 26):

Visual Studio 2017

I had exactly the same problem. It was compiling one day ... and then it wasn't. I wasn't using DependencyProperty which shouldn't be needed as above. The properties were appearing in Intellisense but gave the same message when inserted. I cleaned, built, rebuilt, restarted VS, rebooted etc. All to no avail.

Last ditch try ... I removed all the offending attributes and got a clean compile. Then I put them back and it compiled. I really wasn't expecting that. Somehow VS had gotten its knickers in a twist.

Comment: If rebuild project didn't help. Try change platform from AnyPC to x86 or x64. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Same thing here, like @SonnyD said. Inexplicable but it works.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using VS2017, try to delete bin and obj folders in all projects of your solution, clean the solution and build again. It works for me !

Comment: A simple clean and build of the solution did the trick for me.

Answer (score 13):

Change the build target from AnyCPU to either x86 or x64.  Unsure why AnyCPU does not work.

Comment: You are right. I had similar problem like mentioned above. Restarting VS, rebuild didn't help. Change platform from AnyCPU to other resolves the issue.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense, but it works!
Thank you!

Comment: This seemed to work for me. I'll add that after switching to x86 and cleaning, VS then showed a C# compilation error that was not shown earlier. It was unrelated to WPF (a class had not overridden an abstract method). I think this was the underlying root cause. Once that was fixed I switched back to AnyCPU and all was good. No idea why that error was suppressed in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late but I just ran into this issue on VS 2020.

I tried all 3 options listed above and none of them worked including the CPU build.

[image]

I ended up having to right-click each project, clean, and rebuild. Then it solved the issue...

Really annoying this is still an issue.

Comment: @Nasir Awesome, glad it helped. I am even more annoyed that you just had this issue last month lol.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there're no errors originally, after I modify my class, there're some errors in my class then the Xaml Error `member is not recognized` show. After solving  errors in my class, I pass building the projects, all projects are built without errors, but the errors still show in the `Error List Window`. In the end, I restart Visual Studio, the errors disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with my VS2022, I just removed WindowsBase reference, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting multiple dependency properties for the control, I would use reflection.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserControl", 
typeof(object), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public object UserControl
   {
            get { return GetValue(UserControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UserControlProperty, value); }
   }
```