# WPF Custom User Control - "The member X is not recognized or accessible"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this custom control but cannot access its members from my Main XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="FireflyMmwDiagnostics.Controls.RegisterTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Name="LabelRegisterTitle"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class RegisterTextBox : UserControl
{
    public RegisterTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string RegisterTitle
    {
        get { return this.LabelRegisterTitle.Content.ToString(); }
        set { this.LabelRegisterTitle.Content = value; }
    }
```

And this is what I have in Main XAML where I get the error stating "The member RegisterTitle is not recognized or accessible":

```
<Controls:RegisterTextBox RegisterTitle="This Is A Test"/>
```

I watched a couple of YouTube videos and this is exactly how they did it and it worked for them for some reason.
Please advice on what could be the issue here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You might need to rebuild in order for it to see `RegisterTitle`.

If that doesn't work, make sure you have defined in XAML where `Controls` is in your project, otherwise it definitely won't be able to see it!

For example:

```
<Window xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:FireflyMmwDiagnostics.Controls.RegisterTextBox">
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that.. I will try the suggestion above

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your property to be declared as `Dependency Properties`

This should help as it has example code - [Why am I seeing a “member is not recognized or is not accessible” error on my WPF User Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133795/why-am-i-seeing-a-member-is-not-recognized-or-is-not-accessible-error-on-my-wp)

**Update**

Your code works OK for me without using Dependency Properties, so a couple of things to try:

- In your control, make sure you end it with `</UserControl>`
- Change `Controls:RegisterTextBox` to use a lower case 'c', so `controls:RegisterTextBox`

Comment: Thanks!  I probably don't follow it right so it still doesn't work for me.  Did I make the right changes:  `<Label Name="LabelRegisterTitle"/>   public static readonly DependencyProperty TestMeDependency = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelRegisterTitle", typeof(string), typeof(RegisterTextBox));
       public string RegisterTitle
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestMeDependency); }
            set { SetValue(TestMeDependency, value); }
        }`  <br/>  I'm sorry, I can't get the line break to work...

Comment: I've just tried your code without using `Dependency Properties` and it works fine. Just to check, you do have `</UserControl>` at the end of your user control? Also, change `<Controls:RegisterTextBox RegisterTitle="This Is A Test"/>` to use a lower case 'c', so `<controls:RegisterTextBox RegisterTitle="This Is A Test"/>`

Comment: Yes, I do have `</UserControl>` at the end, just missed for copy/paste.  But for some reason I still cannot get it to work.  By the way, why change to lower case 'c' if it's encapsulated in `namespace FireflyMmwDiagnostics.Controls`?  It doesn't compile with lower 'c'.

Comment: Even when I changed it to lower 'c', in Main XAML, still no luck :( `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FireflyMmwDiagnostics.Controls"`  `<controls:RegisterTextBox RegisterTitle="This Is A Test"/>`.... I will just have to dig and see maybe I have some other issues.  Thank you